# Deploying Django application to Apache running on windows using Jenkins

Tags: django, windows, apache, github, jenkins

I have built a Django web application. I was successfully able to deploy that on Apache running on Windows.

What I now need is to automate the build and deployment process using Jenkins. That is to deploy my Django application residing in GitHub, to get deployed on Apache running on Windows using Jenkins pipeline.

I started that, and so far I am able to build the project successfully using Jenkins. But now I stuck and not able to figure out how to deploy it on Apache running on Windows. Any idea/direction will be highly appreciated.